# Can `What's your favorite “abandoned rule”?` get a historical lock?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, historical-lock

[What's your favorite “abandoned rule”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/112920/561731) has been closed then deleted and undeleted.

Can it be given a historical lock as well?

Comment: Quick - vote for the best answers!!!

Comment: See also [What popular “best practices” are not always best, and why?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/14856)

Comment: Begrudgingly. The question, and it's answers, are pretty marginal. It mostly serves as a shining example of how *not* to ask and answer questions. The post I linked on Programmers.SE is better in this regard.

Comment: Let's wait awhile and see if anyone has any better arguments for saving it.

Comment: @RobertHarvery I don't know about that one. Some jackass got a Great Answer badge just for quoting Raymond Chen

Comment: -10 for this?!  Does locking this question just really piss people off?!

Comment: @AdamRackis wow, when did that happen. How did that happen? LOL

Comment: Locking just because you can lock doesn't make it a valid reason to do so

Comment: @random never said it was, but it ***was*** a good question at some point.

Comment: @random - I don't think anyone has ever said questions should be locked because questions are capable of being locked.  That would be silly.

Comment: When in the time it was posted was that question good?

Comment: -1 I'm usually against deletion, but this questions really not useful, save maybe to convince stubborn people that multiple exit points are okay.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

None of those answers are useful or contribute anything worthwhile to the programming community.

People do a perfectly fine job of figuring out on their own which rules to *violate*, and there are few if any of the existing answers that provide any sort of justification for their encouraged violation of stated rule.

This definitely falls in the "bad question" category, a good example of why we don't allow these types of questions to exist anymore. I'm a fan of only keeping around those *rare exceptions*, the questions that defied all expectations and attracted good, useful answers despite being in poor form. This ain't one.

Besides, the purpose of the historical lock is to preserve specific questions of historical interest. If we start applying it indiscriminately to *all* old questions, it begins to lose its merit. Sometimes we really do need to just let the bad questions die.

Answer (score 8):

Bleh. Delete it again. Those answers are one-liners; there's hardly any useful expansion or justification for any of the "abandoned rules" given.

Comment: are you... feeling ok?

Comment: @Juan: I thought it would be helpful to the discussion to have opposing answers that votes could actually be cast up and down on, rather than a long comment thread (with only upvotes) under the question. Just an idea, but I think I've seen this done before.

Comment: definitely been done before.  Usually with CW to avoid accusations of rep whordom.  Which you did.  Well done, sir

Comment: @Adam: I was thinking about it more as a kevlar vest than a blind trust, but I'm glad that it seems to have worked.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there's some guidance in there that could be useful to new programmers who need to question "established wisdom", but the post doesn't need to continue being open.